# Memory allocation/deallocation when working with C# and C++ unmanaged

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, unmanaged

I am working with some C# and C++ unmanaged code and there are two things I don't understand when dealing with memory. If someone can help me understand:

1. If a variable is dynamically allocated under C# (using new) and then is passed to the C++ unmanaged code. Does that variable memory needs to be deallocated manually under the C++ unmanaged code by the user ?
2. If a variable is dynamically allocated under C++ unmanaged (using new) and then passed to C#, is it safe to say the Garbage Collector will deallocate that memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple!

1. Depends
2. Depends

Eh, Sorry about that.

1. Under typical conditions, C# will keep track of the memory and get rid of it any time after it's no longer used *on the C# side*. It has no way of tracking references on the C++ side, so one common mistake in interop is that the memory is deallocated *before the unmanaged side is done with it* (resulting in loads of FUN). This only applies for cases where the memory is directly referenced, not when its copied (the typical case being a `byte[]` that's pinned for the duration of the unmanaged call). Don't use automatic marshalling when the life-time of the object/pointer being passed to unmanaged code is supposed to be longer than the run of the invoked method.
2. Under typical conditions, C# has no way of tracking memory allocations in the C++ code, so you can't rely on automatic memory management. There are exceptions (e.g. some COM scenarios), but you'll almost always need to manage the memory manually. This usually means sending the pointer back to the C++ code to do the deallocation, unless it used a global allocator of some kind (e.g. CoMemoryInitialize). Remember that in the unmanaged world, there is no one memory manager that you can safely invoke to dispose of memory; you don't really have the necessary information anyway.

This only applies to pointers, of course. Passing integers is perfectly fine, and using automatic marshalling usually means the marshaller takes care of most of the subtleties (though still only in the simplest case, so be careful). Unmanaged code is *unmanaged* - you need to understand perfectly how the memory is allocated, and how, when and who is responsible for cleaning up the memory.

Comment: > common mistake in interop is that the memory is deallocated before the unmanaged side is done. 
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx

Answer (score 3):

1. No, since the object is allocated on managed heap GC will handle deallocation as usual. The problem is you must tell him not to deallocate or change address of the object while it is used from unmanaged code because GC can't know how long you are going to use the object from the unmanaged code. This can be done by PINNING the object.
   See answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143349/c-sharp-how-can-i-pin-an-object-in-memory-without-marshalling-the-object) question.
2. No, since the object is allocated on C++ unmanaged heap GC won't touch it. You have to deallocate it yourself using delete.

Edit:
If you need to allocate an object in managed code and deallocate in unmanaged code or vice versa, It's good to know there is OS heap for this purpose that you can use via [Marshal.AllocHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cyb68cy(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal(v=vs.110).aspx) calls from C#, there will be similar calls in C++.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, whichever `component`/`object` allocates memory should deallocate memory. For every `new` a `delete` by the one which did `new`.

That is the ideal. If not followed for reasons such as you `C++` program may terminate and not exists when allocated memory's lifecycle comes to an end, your `C#` should clean up and visa versa.